# How to fit the coefficients of a first order linear auto-regressive function without noise in the model, and the coefficient are equal?

Tags: regression, time-series, matlab, autoregressive

I have a simple [auto-regressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model#Definition) function:

$x_{i+1} = c - cx_{i}$

It is `linear` and `first order`. There is **no noise** in the model although there is in the data. I am using `Matlab` and have a vector (time series) of numbers that has arisen from a process governed by the above equation. I would like to obtain the value of the coefficient $c$ for the least squares fit to this data.

How can this be done in Matlab by using a library function or toolbox? I have looked at the [ar command](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/ident/ref/ar.html), but fail to see how this can be used in my case. I consider writing instead a function to take the data and calculate the root-mean-squared error over a set of possible values for $c$ choosing the one that is smallest.

Comment: For any $1 \leq i < n$, we have $c = x_{i+1} / (1-x_i)$.

Comment: @cardinal, I think that I made a mistake in the question which I edited, there is no noise modeled although the data contains noise.

Comment: What do you mean "There is no noise in the model but there is in the data"? That doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense on the surface.

Comment: @cardinal, I want to say is that the data I am fitting to has noise, and I want to find the best value of `c` without including any extra parameters to account for the noise

Comment: Even in the regression setting, the gist of my statement still stands. If $\mathbb E( X_{i+1} \mid X_i ) = c - c X_i$, then the least-squares estimate of $c$ is $$ \hat c = \frac{\sum_i x_{i+1}(1-x_i)}{\sum_i (1-x_i)^2} \> .$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes no sense to say there is no noise in the model but there is in the data. I think your model should be a standard AR(1) with a parameter constraint:
$$x_{i+1} = c(1-x_i) + e_i$$
where $e_i$ is white noise.

Then the least squares estimate of $c$ is 
$$\hat{c} = \frac{\sum x_{i+1}(1-x_i)}{\sum (1-x_i)^2}.$$

Comment: (+1) Is this a subtle hint I should be posting my comments as an answer? :)

Comment: Sorry. I think your comment must have gone up at about the same time as my answer. In any case, I didn't see it before I posted. If we both derived the same result, it is probably correct!

Comment: No reason to be sorry at all! :) It was interesting how similar it was. I'm glad you posted it! Cheers.

Comment: @RobHyndman and @cardinal, is this available in Matlab to be computed as a function (just out of curiosity). Also, in the case where the equation has 2 parameters and a squared `x_i` term is there an analogous method of evaluation?

Comment: @Vass. You will need to write your own Matlab function. It should be about 3 lines at most. For the version with squared x_i, you will need to derive the estimators and then write the corresponding function.

Comment: @RobHyndman, thanks for the help. Could you please add how the above least squares estimate was derived? The numerator seems to be the sum of the best `c` values for each dependent value transition, but how does the denominator arise?